# python SimpleHTTPServer not working on a apache2 server

Tags: apache-2.2, python

I have a server on DigitalOcean where I have configured apache2 for hosting. I'm trying to host a directory temporarily using

```
root@computer:~$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8001 ...
```

But when I try opening the site from remote in my web browser, it gives me `503 Service Unavailable`. What am I doing wrong? Do we need to maintain permissions while using python and apache2 at once?

I also used

```
netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"
```

and it shows that python is listening on port 8001.

Comment: What do the python errors say with the 503 messages?

Comment: My browser says `Failed to connect to server 45.55.91.182`. I don't know of any errors python is saying. It's just `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8001 ...`

Comment: Well look at the python console. The module you're using outputs errors to stderr by default.

Comment: The python console has not reported any problems. I believe the problem is not on the python side. The port can't be accessed from remote.

Comment: If the browser is getting a 503 error, that's something your server is sending.

Comment: 503 errors are on all of my ports. I have apache2 configured on port 80